# Can I have Spring Profiles provided by Spring Config Server that would in turn allow for Profile annotated beans to override default beans?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

What I am currently trying achieve is have some "spring.profiles.include" Profiles live in Config-Repo/Spring Config Server so that I can easily enable/disable beans through the use of Profiles. However, what I have noticed is that if I try to do this through Spring Config Server that the profiles in Config-Repo do not affect how configuration classes and beans are created.

If I have my profiles in bootstrap.properties or bootstrap-someProfile.properties it works perfectly. However, having the profiles in Config-Repo does not work.

Below is an example code of what I am trying to achieve. What keeps happening is that the "unreleasedKraken" bean is used when I want the "releasedKraken" bean instead.

```
@Controller
public class TestingController {
  @Autowired
  Kraken kraken;

  /**
   * Test endpoint for using profiles as a way to release/unrelease code
   * @return
   */
  @RequestMapping(value = "/v1/testing/kraken", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public String isThisCodeReleased()
  {
      return kraken.isThisCodeReleased();
  }
}


@Configuration
public class KrakenConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Profile("!releaseTheKraken")
    public Kraken unrelaseKraken()
    {
        final Kraken kraken = () -> "The kraken is not released.";
        return kraken;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("releaseTheKraken")
    public Kraken releaseKraken()
    {
        final Kraken kraken = () -> "The kraken has been released!";
        return kraken;
    }

    interface Kraken {
        String isThisCodeReleased();
    }
}
```

kraken.yaml - lives in Config-Repo

```
spring:
    profiles:
        include: releaseTheKraken
```

Comment: `spring:
    profiles:
       include: releaseTheKraken`
In cloud config should work: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html#boot-features-adding-active-profiles

Comment: @jeff Yup, I have that in my application's cloud config already, but those profiles are not being honored and the beans I want for those profiles are not being created/used.

Comment: I think there is an open issue or pull request, trying to find it.

Comment: This one? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/367

Comment: I read that post and it is what I am looking for as well. Thanks Jeff.

Comment: Yes that is the one.